# No section Error while reading from ConfigParser,

Tags: python, configparser

Hi i have a python script which is reading the values defined in ConfigParser sections.I am able to get the values from the sections and putting into a diffrent variable to use it further.

For example,

```
[path]
DB_CONFIGURATION_PATH:/opt/aor/regression/test_scenario/Config.cfg

[section1]
localhost:127.0.0.1
username:root
password:root
DB_name:test
```

Script1:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import ConfigParser  

configParser = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
configParser.read('/opt/aor/regression/test_scenarios/Config.cfg')

dbconfig_path = configParser.get("Regression_script_path","DB_CONFIGURATION_PATH")
```

Script2:

```
#!/usr/bin/pythoni

import os
import sys
#import ReadConfigurationFile
from ReadConfigurationFile import *
db_path=dbconfig_path
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('db_path')
host=config.get("section1","localhost")
print host
```

This is throwing error as :

```
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'section1'
```

Can you tell me what is the problem here?

Comment: how come script 1 works? The name of the section is : `Regression_script_path` in the script, but `path`, in the cfg file

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but you don't seem to read the cfg file in script2.py. Also, your shebang is wrong (probably) in script 2, and I would recommend to change it to `#!/usr/bin/env python` in case someone runs in a virtualenv